# Merging ranked lists of tuples based on common id

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following sorted lists of tuples:

```
list1 = [(0.2, 'a'), (0.4, 'b'), (0.5,'d')]
list2 = [(0.1, 'a'), (0.3, 'c'), (0.7, 'x')]
list3 = [(0.5, 'c'), (0.6, 'a'), (0.5, 'b')]
```

I want to create an overall ranked list based on the common letters as follows:

1. If the letter is common in all three lists, add the three individual values
2. If the letter is only common between two lists, add the two individual values and a 1
3. If the element is only in one list, add 2 to its value

Expected result:

```
[(0.9, 'a'), (1.8, 'c'), (1.9, 'b'), (2.5, 'd'), (2.7, 'x')]
```

What is working:

I am able to get the expected result if the item is common in all three lists but I am unable to get correct results if it's the other cases.

Code snippet

```
list1 = [(0.2, 'a'), (0.4, 'b'), (0.5, 'd')]
list2 = [(0.1, 'a'), (0.3, 'c'), (0.7, 'x')]
list3 = [(0.5, 'c'), (0.6, 'a'), (0.5, 'b')]
priority_result = [] # when element is common in all 3 lists
twos_array = [] #when element is common in only two lists

result = [(s1, l1 + l1) for (l1, s1), (l1, s2) in zip(list1, list2)]
print(result)
for (score, resultID) in list1:
    for (score1, resultID1) in list2:
        for (score2, resultID2) in list3:
            if(resultID == resultID1 or resultID == resultID2):                    
                result = [(score + score1 + score2, resultID)]
                priority_result.extend(result)
            elif(resultID == resultID1 and resultID != resultID2):
                result = [(score + score1 + 1, resultID)]
                twos_array.extend(result)
```

How can I work on this to produce the desired outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap the order of the tuples to create a mapping:

```
d1 = dict(x[::-1] for x in list1)
d2 = dict(x[::-1] for x in list2)
d3 = dict(x[::-1] for x in list3)
```

Now you can make a union of the keys, since `dict.keys` returns a `set`-like object:

```
keys = d1.keys() | d2.keys() | d3.keys()
```

The rest can be done with `dict.get`:

```
result = {k: d1.get(k, 1) + d2.get(k, 1) + d3.get(k, 1) for k in keys}
```

Turning this into a sorted list is straightforward:

```
sorted(x[::-1] for x in result.items())
```

Let's say your lists were in a meta-list now:

```
lists = [list1, list2, list3]
keys = set().union(*lists)
dicts = [dict(x[::-1] for x in l) for l in lists]
result = {k: sum(d.get(k, 1) for d in dicts) for k in keys}
result = sorted(x[::-1] for x in result.items())
```

---

Here is a slightly simpler solution:

```
mapping = dict.fromkeys(set().union(*lists), len(lists))
for v, k in itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists):
    mapping[k] += v - 1
result = sorted(x[::-1] for x in result.items())
```

---

You can use `collections.Counter` to do most of the math for you:

```
c = Counter()
for lst in lists:
    c.update({k: v - 1 for v, k in lst})
result = [(v + len(lists), k) for k, v in c.items()]
```

The same thing with a regular `collections.defaultdict` is:

```
d = defaultdict(int)
for v, k in itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists):
    d[k] += v - 1
result = [(v + len(lists), k) for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: @Mark `d1.get(k, 1) + d2.get(k, 1) + d3.get(k, 1)` does exactly what op asked, no? You set 1 for every dict that is missing the key

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Not sure about the DV.

Comment: @Kumbudzi. I've added a simpler answer

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [(0.2, 'a'), (0.4, 'b'), (0.5, 'd')]
list2 = [(0.1, 'a'), (0.3, 'c'), (0.7, 'x')]
list3 = [(0.5, 'c'), (0.6, 'a'), (0.5, 'b')]

d = {}
for t in list1 + list2 + list3:
    d.setdefault(t[1], []).append(t[0])
lst = [(sum(v, 3 - len(v)), k) for k, v in d.items()]
print(lst)  # [(0.9, 'a'), (1.9, 'b'), (2.5, 'd'), (1.8, 'c'), (2.7, 'x')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. If you initialize using `dict.fromkeys` on a union of all the keys, you can just add directly without `setdefault`

Comment: @MadPhysicist `dict.fromkeys` will initialize all the list with one instance of `[]` so all the added values will be added for all the keys: `d = dict.fromkeys([t[1] for t in list1 + list2 + list3], [])`. Or i misunderstand?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. You initialize it with 3

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
x = list1 + list2 + list3
y = [l[1] for l in x]
print(sorted([((3 - y.count(key)) + sum(next(zip(*l))), key) for key, l in groupby(sorted(x, key=ig(1)), key=ig(1))], key=ig(0)))
```

---

```
[(0.9, 'a'), (1.8, 'c'), (1.9, 'b'), (2.5, 'd'), (2.7, 'x')]
```

This code concatenates the lists and creates also another list for only the key, and groups by the keys, sums up the value. Also it adds the expected increase in the value according to the number of occurrences.

And finally it sorts by the summed and modified values.

Comment: `[*zip(*x)]` -> `list(zip(*x))`, or just `[e[1] for e in x]`